# Firebase cloud messaging minimum support sdk

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to ask that, how can I use the firebase cloud messaging to support my current minimum sdk version 9 of my app? Or should I use back google cloud messaging?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to support Android versions < 14 you need to use Google Play libraries (or Firebase libraries) that have been released before February 2017 (version 10.2)

In February Google released Google Play services and Firebase 10.2 and changed the minimum required version of Android to 14:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#february_2017_-_version_102

> **Android version 2.3.x (Gingerbread) Deprecation**
>
> Google Play services 10.2.x is the first release that no longer
>   includes full support for Android version 2.3.x (Gingerbread). Apps
>   developed using SDK release 10.2.x and later require a minimum Android
>   API level of 14 and cannot be installed on devices running API
>   level below 14.
>
> To learn more about your options, including building
>   multiple APKs to extend your app's support for Android Gingerbread,
>   see the [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html).